# Mist in Mistborn series

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, wax-wayne-novels, the-final-empire

In the Mistborn trilogy, and the new Wax and Wayne novels, their seems to be a sense of increase in power in the mist. Does the mist actually increase the allomantic powers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, though it's never been explicitly stated.

The mists are an artifact of Preservation, and Allomancy uses Preservation's power to fuel itself. We know from the first trilogy that the mists *can* power Allomancy. Vin used them for that purpose just before she took up Preservation herself.

During the era of the Final Empire, Preservation was exerting all of it's energy just trying to keep Ruin in check; the amount of power it had left to send into the world was very limited. (In fact, during the *Mistborn* trilogy it's essentially dying).

Now that Harmony has taken over, he can afford to release more of that power into the mists. While Vin seems to have been unique in her ability to channel the mists directly, it makes sense that being inside them allows the Allomancer "better access" to the magic that drives their powers.

Comment: Harmony may have stopped it being something that can be consumed, though also Vin was probably much more powerful than many of the mistings around in Elendel and also was a full Mistborn, and was also one of Preservation's 'chosen'

Comment: I was under the impression that because Vin was a sliver of infinity (she has held the power of a shard, specifically when she released Ruin from the Well of Ascension), this is what gave her the ability to actually absorb the mists and convert that into some form of power for her Allomancy. Because she had already held Preservation AKA the mists, it was nothing new to her.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there were hints of her using the mists even before she took up Preservation, it just wasn't clear what was happening; e.g. during her fight with the Lord Ruler, after she lost her earring?